# Problem with combining display: inline; and position:absolute;

Tags: css-position, display

I found this example in W3school website [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp)

I'm trying to change the image's display from 'block' to 'inline' and found out that the .container and the .overlay are becoming a little bit bigger than the image.

Why is that happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>

<div class="container">
  <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_avatar.png' alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: bottom;` along with `display: inline;`.

Comment: Can you explain what is causing the problem?

Comment: That's the standard behavior of display inline and inline-block.

Comment: Please, can you explain to me about each behavior are you talking about?

Comment: By default, an image is rendered inline to the the normal text. So to avoid that we need to either change its display property to block or we just use vertical-align to position as per our needs.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't explain what makes the .container bigger than the image

Comment: That is the only explanation. You being more sure than me, please let me know when you have another explanation. I might learn something new from you. I'll wait.